# Docker doesn't run entrypoint script

Tags: bash, docker

Can't get why Docker ignoring my docker-endpoint.sh

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite expires

RUN set -ex \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache gd pdo_mysql zip

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY config/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN set -xe \
    chown -R www-data:www-data . \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "Hello"

exec "$@"
```

I would expect to see "Hello". Container starts normally, no errors, but Apache doesn't work. Bash is installed. I also tried to replace #!/bin/bash with #!/bin/sh or even remove it - same result.

UPD. php.ini

```
[PHP]

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 120

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 256M

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 10M

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 10M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20

; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-fopen
allow_url_fopen = Off

[opcache]
; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled
opcache.enable=1

; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled for the CLI version of PHP
opcache.enable_cli=1

; The OPcache shared memory storage size.
opcache.memory_consumption=128

; The amount of memory for interned strings in Mbytes.
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8

; The maximum number of keys (scripts) in the OPcache hash table.
; Only numbers between 200 and 100000 are allowed.
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000

; How often (in seconds) to check file timestamps for changes to the shared
; memory storage allocation. ("1" means validate once per second, but only
; once per request. "0" means always validate)
opcache.revalidate_freq=2

; If enabled, a fast shutdown sequence is used for the accelerated code
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your Dockerfile & endpoint, and ran two commands, after making one modification (commenting out the php.ini copy)

```
docker build . -t me/foo
docker run me/foo
```

The image built & the container started successfully, displaying `Hello` in the console. I don't think the ENTRYPOINT is an issue.

I would inspect your php.ini file.

If you can post it in your original question and add a comment to my answer when added I would be glad to review again.

Comment: What is your OS? I'm on Win, may it be related to encoding, new lines etc?

Comment: I added php.ini

Comment: @ymakux I'm on MacOS & double-checked again with your php.ini. All looks good. Yes, it may be an issue with new lines in the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file. Please do test, and if you follow up I'll remove my answer  (which maybe should have been a comment instead, depending on who you ask)

Comment: The question appears to be: "[I] Can't get why Docker [is] ignoring my docker-endpoint.sh". If the answer is: "Docker isn't ignoring your docker-endpoint.sh script, it's actually a problem with your php.ini", then this would be an answer to the question.